# How to trigger only the action related to the correct button with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have simple jQuery UI function. but I have multiple buttons where I want to show different dialog windows. My problem is that when I push button all dialog windows on page opens but I need only the one who is under the same `.dialog-frame` class div.

```
$(function() {
  $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false, 
    show: {},
    hide: {} 
  });
  $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

And here is my html

```
<div class="dialog-frame">
  <div class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>AaAaAAAAAaaaaaA</p>
  </div> 
  <a class="opener">A</a>
</div>

<div class="dialog-frame">
  <div class="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>BbbBbbbBBBBBBbb</p>
  </div> 
  <a class="opener">B</a>
</div>
```

Working Fiddle there : **[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/MfegM/2203/)**

Comment: Use the event target to get the correct dialog, as written, `$( ".dialog" )` will get all the dialog divs, since they all have that class. Sidenote: <a> tags without a href or name are technically illegal syntax and might throw errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but you could assign the dialogs ids and then give a data attribute to the anchors.  When an anchor is clicked, just retrieve the id from that anchor's data and open the proper dialog using that ID.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {},
    hide: {}
  });
  $(".opener").click(function() {
    var dialogID = $(this).data("dia");
    $("#" + dialogID).dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="dialog-frame">
  <div class="dialog" id="dialogA" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>AaAaAAAAAaaaaaA</p>
  </div>
  <a class="opener" data-dia="dialogA">A</a>
</div>

<div class="dialog-frame">
  <div class="dialog" id="dialogB" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>BbbBbbbBBBBBBbb</p>
  </div>
  <a class="opener" data-dia="dialogB">B</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution !

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the proper selector in your DOM

For your case it is probable **prev()** since your element is placed after your opener in your tree DOM.

So it will do something like :

```
  $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    $(this).prev(".dialog").dialog( "open" );
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide us a JsFiddle or a CodePen so we can have a better  idea of what you are doing. I've never seen dialog() before so I assume it is a function linked to your dialog-frame and I can't help with that if I don't know what you are using.

Comment: dialog opens popup. its from jQuery UI. sorry i havent used JsFiddle or CodePen :D

Comment: It seems like dialog creates new elements outside the dialog-frames and moves the .dialog elements inside.  So prev doesn't work because they're no longer in the same location

Comment: yea, that might be the problem. You have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The only way I can think of is giving the dialogs ids and the anchors a data attribute with those ids

Comment: If I manually give id to everything. how should my jquery look so I don't have to re-wright it for every id?

Comment: @DanielsV I posted an answer.  You won't have to change the jquery very much but you will have to add ids and the data attributes